# Is it safe to check user login Session with GET variable?

Tags: php, session

lets say i have a session called $_SESSION['id_user']
and it stores session of the user id.  Lets say that the user profile is www.example.com/profile.php?id=123
if I want to check if that profile is the user and if i do something like

> if(isset($_SESSION['id_user']))
>   {
>   if($_SESSION['id_user']==$_GET['id']){print something since this is the users own profile}
> else{print nothing}
>   }

Is the above code good enought? or is their any security problem? or is it wise to compare GET variable with SESSION variable? its not printing anything that will give user identity away or anything I just want to show a (edit profile button) for the user that is visiting his own profile.

Comment: why would you want to compare the session with the get variable if you can open the users profile using the session variable?

Comment: This is fine: its not like your using `/profile.php?logged_in=true`

Comment: If there is a security risk here, it is not from comparing the $_GET-variable to $_SESSION, it is the fact that the URL exposes the user ID to begin with.

Comment: @thomas: Maybe you are allowed to see other people's profiles, but with less information?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is safe - the session is stored on the server and a user cannot change the session data manually. Unless their session is [hijacked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), then only they will be able to see their own profile.

For piece of mind (and to prevent possible SQL injections I'd just cast the two variables as `(int)`s before using them (also cuts down on having to write `$_SESSION['id_user']` multiple times. I would also use `===` which checks the variables without any type conversions.

As mentioned in the comments by Thomas, if you've got the users ID in the session already, then unless you need to (differentiate between profiles), just use that and don't send the user ID over GET.

Comment: Yeah as far as the typecasting is concerned as you stated, you can use intval($_GET['id']) if you're really worried about it.